# Move marker on Openstreet map - Leaflet

Tags: maps, leaflet

I use the following plug-in to move the marker on the map - https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker

Faced with such a problem that the zoom the map, markers are beginning to jump on it. How is that correct?

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @der_michael I think the problem is that when you zoom in/out the markers do not stay on their **map** position (on the street) but on the **screen** position while zooming. This causes them to _fly_ to the new position on the map before they continue moving. Not really a _problem_ though.

Comment: @Krxldfx could also be that he is simple talking about the jumps in gps location fixes when conditions are not optimal...

Comment: For demo: http://lf.dobrohost.net/

Comment: Looks like lib error for me.

Comment: Can you please post your code or create a JSFiddle or something? Would be hard to help you without otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need a plugin.
this should do it

```
marker.setLatLng([lat, long]);
```